# how to trigger an event whenever a tweet is updated

Tags: twitter, listeners, ajax-polling

I wanted to know how to trigger an event (say. storing a tweet from a particular user in a text file or mailing it etc.) when a particular user updates his tweets. Do we need to poll for the updates every few seconds or is there any other way out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can poll every few seconds (more like every minute, otherwise you'll run into the API rate limit), or you could look at using the [Streaming API](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api)